# How to remove custom tag in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove following tag from string.

```
[caption id="attachment_9" align="alignleft" width="137" caption="test"][/caption]
```

How do I remove it using php's preg_replace?

I tried several regular expression, but failed all.

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL [caption][/caption] sets, or JUST ones with id, align, width and caption set?

Comment: @Jamie Wong // I would like to remove all caption sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$output_string = preg_replace('#\[caption[^\]]*\](.*?)\[/caption\]#m', "$1", $input_string)
```

or if you also want to remove anything between the opening and closing tag, just change `"$1"` to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

Tested here: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/\[caption.+caption\]/";
$str = "Otherstuff[caption id=\"attachment_9\" align=\"alignleft\" width=\"137\" caption=\"test\"][/caption]Something else";
$rpltxt = "@";
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

Comment: -1 Two major problems with this. 1. Fails because you don't check for greedy conditions. "hello[caption][/caption]NOT IN A CAPTION[caption][/caption]world" will get replaced "helloworld". 2. This doesn't accommodate for caption sets that span multiple lines. Will fail for "[caption]\n[/caption]". As another note, you have an unescaped " inside $str, meaning that code won't even run.

Comment: I corrected item 2. An oversight while quickly posting the generated code from that link. Regarding item 1, you are absolutely right. His question did not provide much context and I found a quick solution. Amber has the better solution.